# c# - send text using httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, httpwebrequest

I want to scrape the HTML page and need to enter value to textbox and click button (hyperlink button without id, but I know the javascript function).

HTML Elements:

```
<input type="text" class="searchinput" id="txtSearch" placeholder="Search Term Here">
<a class="k-button searchbtn" onclick="javascript:Search()">
```

Code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.123.com/pages/search.aspx");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.CookieContainer = cc;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
   var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("txtSearch=12345&btn=Click");
   stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string result = String.Empty;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
  result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I tried above code but did not help to get the desire output. Is there any way to enter value to textbox and call javascript function.

Comment: What is your question? What is the desired output? What is the observed output?

Answer (score 0):

HttpWebRequest only downloads the raw text of the web page.
In order for it to function like a web page, you need to load it into some kind of a web browser which knows how to parse it, execute scripts, generate postback requests, store cookies, etc.

If this is a Windows Forms application, you can use a WebBrowser control for that.
Just put it on the form and try this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HtmlElement txtFirstName = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("firstName");
  txtFirstName.SetAttribute("value", "new value");
  webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("callMe");
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  webBrowser1.Navigate("file:///D:/aaa/test.html");
}
```

The content of the test.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        function callMe(){
            alert('Called me');
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="firstName" value="original value"></Input>
    <button type="button" onClick="callMe();">Click Me!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```